# How to dislay the buttons according to various values

Tags: typescript, ionic2

How to display the button in the html file on the basis of the values stored in the `result`?

**page1.ts**

```
 class page1 {
    let result: string; //possible values of result can be 'additon', 
                        //'multiply','divide'.

    constructor(public serviceClass : ServiceClass){
     this.initialzie();
    }

    additon(){
      this.result = 'addition';
   }

    modulus(){
     //logic for this function.
    }

    initialize(){
    this.result = this.serviceClass.someFunction();
    }
    }
```

**page1.html**

```
//headers and title already implemented.

// buttons to implement now.
//**condition**: The below button is only shown on the basis of the value 
                  //populated in the result variable in .ts class.

<div> //if result = 'multiply, 'divide' then show this button.How to 
                     //implement this?
<button ion-button (click)="addition()">ADD ME</button>
</div>

<div> //if result = 'addition' then show this button.How to implement this?
<button ion-button (click)="modulus()">Modulus</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `*ngIf`

```
<div *ngIf="result == 'multiply' || result == 'divide' "> 
<button ion-button (click)="addition()">ADD ME</button>
</div>


<div *ngIf="result == 'addition'"> 
<button ion-button (click)="modulus()">Modulus</button>
</div>
```

Comment: when I click ADD ME button the value of result get `addition` but the button does not replace with `Modulus`

Comment: where is your addition function

Comment: when I click on addition() then somehow it updates the value of `result = addition`, so when the value changes to `addition` the button should change to `Modulus`.This is the required logic i need to implement.

Comment: also addition() is in .ts file.